# Upgrade from php 7.4.11 to 7.4.13

Tags: php, centos, php-7.4

I have a centos linux server which is running on php v7.4.11 right now. However, I want to upgrade to the v7.4.13 which was released just a few days ago.

The question is how do I install exact version of php, the commands that I find only specify `php74` etc. not the exact version like `php7.4.13` etc. When I try to do `sudo yum install php74` it only installs php 7.4.11

[check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foNAT.png)

EDIT:

I have removed the php-cli and then when I try `sudo yum install php php-cli` it defaults to php v7.4.11:

[please see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZakD.png)

**Any idea how can I change these default packages to php 7.4.13 instead?**

Comment: Most package based linux systems will lag behind the latest release for a while.  If you want to install the latest then you may have to download it and install it yourself (or find whatever the equivalent of PPA's are for centos).

Comment: if you really need to keep updating just for patch versions, then you should look into using docker, then would be a case of simply changing the image version, or rebuilding the image if you make it to build from source

Comment: Be patient, a matter of weeks since it's a stable version. But of course you just have to get the sources and compile yourself. If you are looking for performance you can tweak many things at compilation time, everything is well explained in the source archive https://www.php.net/downloads.php#v7.4.13

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to do sudo yum install php74 it only installs php 7.4.11

This isn't correct. Your screenshot does not indicate this. The `php74` package by Remi does not reflect the exact PHP 7.4 version in any way. To see the exact version available, you can try:

```
yum install php74-php-common
```

If you do not see PHP 7.4.13, then run `yum clean all`, before running the above command.

> I have removed the php-cli and then when I try

You're mixing up repositories (Amazon one with Remi's). Moreover, you are mixing up ways of installation: single version vs software collection. Amazon repo is likely to be behind, Remi repository is quite up-to-date always and is brought by one of the core PHP devs.

As a rule, I would recommend "software collection"s available in Remi repositories, so use (extend the command with the exact PHP modules you need):

```
yum install php74-php-cli php74-php-common php74-php-fpm ...
```

This installs PHP 7.4 in a separate installation tree under `/opt/remi`.

If you really want the *default* PHP (that is, single/system) version of PHP upgraded, then you must follow through [repository wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) choosing "Type of installation = Default". It will then give you all the necessary commands for upgrading the system PHP version.